# Extract string between full-stops unless CO

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling with regex to extract part of a string between fullstops, but ignore a full-stop if it is preceded by specific letters (e.g. CO. in the example). We can assume the relevant chunk always ends with " LTD."

Case 1:

```
string = "FREDS CHIP SHOP.  S & B SERVICES CO. & SONS LTD. 1-12 THE STREET"
```

I Want: `"S & B SERVICES CO. & SONS LTD."`

Case 2:

```
string = "SOME TEXT.  BUSINESS NAME LTD. 1-12 THE STREET"
```

I want `"BUSINESS NAME LTD."`

Case 3:

```
string = "SIMPLE BUSINESS NAME LTD. 1-12 THE STREET"
```

I want `"SIMPLE BUSINESS NAME LTD."`

I currently have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import re

vnumber_name = "FREDS CHIP SHOP.  S & B SERVICES CO. & SONS LTD. 1-12 THE STREET"
#vnumber_name = "SOME TEXT.  BUSINESS NAME LTD. 1-12 THE STREET"
#vnumber_name = "SIMPLE BUSINESS NAME LTD. 1-12 THE STREET"

def test(vnumber_name):
    #ltd = re.search(r'.+\sLTD[.]?', vnumber_name)
    ltd = re.search(r'[.?][\s]{1,2}(?:[^.]+|(?!CO.))LTD[.]?', vnumber_name)
    if ltd:
        print "got it: " + ltd.group(0)
    else:
        print "nothing"

test(vnumber_name)
```

which is not right.

I could create some if clauses, but it would be great to get it with a single line of regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will presumably want to exempt more than one abbreviation, so here's something more flexible using "negative lookbehind": Match from the start of the string to the next period that does *not* follow certain strings (`CO` or `CORP` for this example). The non-greedy `.*?` (followed by a period) causes you to match up to the *first* such period.

```
.*?(?<!..CO|CORP)\.
```

This will allow you to properly break up your string into "sentences". If you're only interested in the ones that end in LTD, you can then select those.

Comment: Many thanks. I hadn't realised there was a negative lookbehind.  Thanks for the explanation

Comment: You are welcome. But unless you only plan to match the three cases you gave as examples, you should reconsider the answer you accepted: It won't work with the example I gave in the comment (and various others).

Comment: You are right! OK need to give this some more thought. Thanks for the tip-off

Comment: Is there something wrong with using (or adapting) my solution?

Comment: No - but I can't get it to work on a script. I get:   sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

But it does work fine here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ so I am just trying to work it out.

Comment: Oops! Ok, my bad. The python engine won't accept the `CO|CORP` disjunction in the lookbehind. :-( You can still solve your problem by just having `CO` in the lookbehind (no disjunction), or padding all alternates to the same length with dots (see edit). Ugly, but it works!

Comment: One more thing to consider: You may want to add word boundaries to avoid the chance of false matches: `.*?(?<!..\bCO|\bCORP)\.`